# Assign Parse current user pointer column value to another class column (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a Parse class called User which has a pointer called bank to Class Bank.The Bank class has a column called name.I want to assign the current user's  bank name to another class (ATM) column called atmName. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First get the bank object and atm object:

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
var bank = user["bank"]
var atm  = PFObject(className:"ATM")
```

and then store the attribute to the atm object:

```
atm["atmName"] = bank["name"]
```

finally, we need to save the atm object to the Parse server:

```
atm.saveInBackgound()
```